# Trouble accessing method from module?

Tags: ruby, module, nameerror

I'm including someone else's module, which seems to be split across multiple files.  It looks something like this:

alfred.rb:

```
require 'alfred/ui'

module Alfred
  <code>
end
```

alfred/ui.rb:

```
module Alfred
  class Logger
    def info(msg)
      logger.info msg
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to access the `info` method from my code, which has `require "alfred"` at the top, using this syntax:

```
Alfred::Logger.info("my message")
```

which is not working, and results in `#<NameError: uninitialized constant Alfred::Logger>`.

Secondly, I would love if someone could explain *how* exactly Ruby "constructs" a module that is split across several files like this.  Does the code from `alfred/ui.rb` get included at the end of `alfred.rb` at the beginning where the `require` line is?  Does it all get put together in some other fashion?  Maybe it doesn't even matter, but it seems it would help me wrap my head around it better.

The full code of the module I'm using is [at Github](https://github.com/zhaocai/alfred-workflow) in case anyone is interested.

Can someone help explain why I can't use the method this way, and what might be done to fix it?

Comment: I get another error `NoMethodError: undefined method `info' for Alfred::Logger:Class`. From where do you do that call?

Comment: but in the guthub repo I dont see definition of the `Logger` class inside the `Alfred` module. I se only `class LogUI < ::Logger`... Try `Alfred::LogUI.info("my message")`

Comment: Oh interesting, it looks like the class has been updated since I last downloaded it.  I'll download the latest and give that a shot when I'm at home tonight.

Answer (score 0):

`#info` is a **instance** method, meaning it only exists on instances of the Logger class.  If you want to call it directly from your code, you'd call `Alfred::Logger.new.info "some message"`, but that seems a bit odd.  Usually that type of thing is used internally by the library.

If it had been defined like a class method:

```
module Alfred   
  class Logger   
    def self.info(msg)  
      logger.info msg   
    end   
  end
end
```

then you would  be able to call it as you're attempting.

Comment: For your code, you could try something like this: `@my_logger = Alfred::Logger.new` at the top of code, then throughout do `@my_logger.info "foo!"`

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation.  I had instance/class methods reversed in my head.  I'm still not able to instantiate the logger using the syntax you provided, however.  I get the same `uninitialized constant Alfred::Logger` error as before.  Any ideas on that?